# How to handle multiple form submits without individual click event handlers

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two forms in my mvc application, All the forms are displayed dynamically, how can I bind ajax call to those form submit button with out losing validation. 
Following is the code which I have.

```
 //form1
        <form id="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                    <input type="text" name="fname1" id="fname1" placeholder="Full Name">
                                                                                                    <input type="email" name="femail1" id="femail1" placeholder="your@email.com">
                                                    <input id="send1" type="button" >
                                                </form>

    //form2

    <form id="form1" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                                <input type="text" name="fname1" id="fname1" placeholder="Full Name">

                                                <input type="email" name="femail1" id="femail1" placeholder="your@email.com">
                                                <input id="button2" type="button">
                                            </form>



//Jquery code

    $('#button1').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var fname           =$('#fname1').val();
            var femail          =$('#femail1').val();
            var fphone          =$('#fphone1').val();

            var error           =0;

            $('#fname1,#femail1,#fphone1').css('border', '');

            if(fname=='Full Name' || fname==''){
                $('#fname1') .css('border','solid 1px red');
                error=1;

            }

            var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
            if(femail == 'your@email.com' || !emailPattern.test(femail)) {           
                $('#femail1').css('border','solid 1px red');                 
                error = 1;
            }


            if(fphone=='____-_____' || fphone==''){
                $('#fphone1').css('border','solid 1px red');
                error=1;

            }   



          //do ajax call


            return false;



        });

//jquery code for button 2

    $('#button2').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            var fname           =$('#fname1').val();
            var femail          =$('#femail1').val();
            var fphone          =$('#fphone1').val();

            var error           =0;

            $('#fname1,#femail1,#fphone1').css('border', '');

            if(fname=='Full Name' || fname==''){
                $('#fname1') .css('border','solid 1px red');
                error=1;

            }

            var emailPattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
            if(femail == 'your@email.com' || !emailPattern.test(femail)) {           
                $('#femail1').css('border','solid 1px red');                 
                error = 1;
            }


            if(fphone=='____-_____' || fphone==''){
                $('#fphone1').css('border','solid 1px red');
                error=1;

            }   



          //do ajax call


            return false;



        });
```

Like I said these forms are dynamically loaded I need to perform ajax call like above.

Comment: Please phrase your question in a way that you are not asking for "the best".  Describe any information about your specific problem, provide any existing code that you have trying to solve that problem, and let people help you with your specific problem.  Asking for "the best" is a quick way to get a post closed for being opinionated or overly broad.

Comment: @Taplar I'm asking for a way to approach this problem. Brief description would be helpful for me , Like architecture view to approach this problem

Comment: This site is about helping people solve issues with their specific code problems, **not** advice.  Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for the kinds of questions Stackoverflow desires.  After your specific problem is solved, if you want to ask if there is a better way, or to make it more performant, you can ask such questions on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How are you registering your 3 button click events for 3 forms ? is the code inside all these 3 click handlers same ?

Comment: @Shyju Yes, it gets the details and does a post to controller, The only difference is validation check, validation check will be performed to that particular form

Comment: Still did not answer the question. You should include some relevant code in the question so people can understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Let me update my question.

Comment: @Shyju Can you please look a the question now

Comment: hint: research delegated events in jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code you want to execute inside the click handler of each button click is same, you may consider using a more generic jQuery selector to wireup your form `submit` event .Currently you are using `Id` as the jQuery selector. Since Id's should be unique in the document, that will work only for a single element. That means you need to wire up multiple click handlers, one for each id (that is what you are doing now)

Add a html 5 data attribute to all your forms and use that to wire up your form `submit` event.

Here i am adding a `data-ajax-form` data attribute to the form.

```
<form id="form1" action="someUrl" method="post" data-ajax-form>

</form>
```

Now use this new data attribute for your jQuery selector when wiring up the ajax form submit behavior.

```
$(function() {

    $(document).on("submit","[data-ajax-form]",function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var $form=$(this);
        alert("Submitting the form");
        var data = $form.serialize();
        alert("serialized form : "+data);

        //Your other common code

        $.post($form.attr("action"),data).done(function(res) {

            //do something with the response
            console.log(res);
        });
    });

});
```

Using jQuery `on` to wire up events will make it work with **current and future elements of the DOM**. So you need to use that for dynamically injected elements. Here i am using `$(document)` with the `on` method. You may use a more specific selector there. For example, you can use the container div id (to which your forms are dynamically being added)

```
$("#yourFormContainerDiv").on("submit","[data-ajax-form]",function(e) {

});
```

Assuming `yourFormContainerDiv` is the id of a div which your page has , and to which your dynamic forms are being added to.

You might also consider using a client side validation library like [jQuery validate](https://jqueryvalidation.org/). The mvc helper methods render the input element markups with the relevant attribute used by this library (based on the view model property type/data annotations). Take a look at [Adding validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/validation)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Implementing now...

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a feature called Event Delegation in JQuery. Normally, you wire up your events to elements but this becomes a problem when you have dynamic elements.

In this case, you can "delegate" your events to the parent and let it handle for its child contents. For e.g., the code below has existing 2 buttons and then a 3rd button is dynamically added.

What I did is wired the event to the parent div and then used the syntax below for event delegation. You can learn more about it here https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // event delegation
        $(".parent").on("click","button", function () {
            alert("Post form");
        })

        // dynamically add 3rd button
        $(".parent").append("<button>Button 3</button>");
    })
</script>

<div class="parent">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
</div>
```